# how to get the user control itself when clicked on one of its components in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I made a user control and added in the main form a click event for a panel in it. i want to get the user control so i could use other things in it, but the sender would be a panel and not a user control.
this is what I have

```
void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel p = (Panel)(sender);
    //UserControl1 tmp = .... 
    label1.Text = "Item Code:" + tmp.pro.product_code;
    label2.Text = "Name:" + tmp.pro.product_name;
    label3.Text = "Price:" + tmp.pro.product_price;             
}
```

how can i do this?
thanks

Comment: What kind of question is this? Can you expand more.

Comment: what i want to get is a pointer of the UserControl that contains the panel that was clicked on.

Comment: Change the sender object to the UserControl from where you raise the event.  It would just be `this`.  You didn't post the code where you raise the event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too certain if I read this correctly, but from what you're saying, I gather that you have a panel and a user control on the main form, and you want to update the panel on the main form with values from the user control. If this is Correct, then try this

Approach 1:

```
void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel p = (Panel)(sender);
    UserControl tmp;
    foreach (Control control in MainForm.Controls)
    {
        if (control is UserControl)
        {
            if (control.Name == "MyUserControlName")
            {
                tmp = control as UserControl;
            }
        }
    }

    //Let's check that we got the control
    if (tmp != null)
    {
        //Now find the controls / Variables that are holding your values in the user control first - I'm assuming textboxes

        TextBox txtProductCode = tmp.Controls.Find("TextBox1",false);
        TextBox txtProductName = tmp.Controls.Find("TextBox2",false);
        TextBox txtProductPrice = tmp.Controls.Find("TextBox3",false);

        label1.Text = "Item Code:" + txtProductCode.Text;
        label2.Text = "Name:" + txtProductName.Text;
        label3.Text = "Price:" + txtProductPrice.Text; 
    }
}
```

Approach 2:

Everything is the same as approach one except that you remove the foreach loop and replace the following

```
    UserControl tmp;
    foreach (Control control in MainForm.Controls)
    {
        if (control is UserControl)
        {
            if (control.Name == "MyUserControlName")
            {
                tmp = control as UserControl;
            }
        }
    }
```

with this

```
var tmp = MainFForm.Controls.Find("MyUserControlName",false);
```

Where "MainForm" is the name of you main form where the user control is placed and "MyUserControlName" is the name of your user control

Comment: the panel is in the user control, i want to get the pointer of the user control when clicked on the panel within it.
let's sayi have a picturebox and some labels in my usercontrol, and when clicked on the picturebox i want to change the lables' texts. the sender in this case would ba a picturebox, therefore i can't get to the lables of the usercontrol. how do i get the user control itself so i could get to its other components?

Comment: Oh ok, then the code still applies. The key is to find the control, either by looping through the control on the main form or searching it directly as per my edit.